# How to uninstall or downgrade selenium webdriver in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

I'm trying to downgrade or uninstall the gem "Selenium-Webdriver 3.1.0" to "Selenium-Webdriver 2.53.3" 
I used the following command to uninstall

```
gem uninstall selenium-webdriver --version 3.1.0
```

It results as successfully uninstalled selenium-webdriver-3.1.0. But when i list the gems, i find the version 3.1.0 again.

Can someone please let me know how to uninstall it ?

Thanks,
Dhanabalan

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, that is to uninstall ruby and then re-install with older version of selenium webdriver.

Let me know if anyone has anyother solutions. Thanks!